# How to get a custom php application run from a subdirectory of a CI application on Google App Engine Standard?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-php

I am a bit confused about how to set the app.yaml up in order to get my work done. Previously I had this same codeigniter application running elsewhere with `/support` sub-directory serving a custom php support desk application. It had no issues. Good ol' apache served it without any issue.

Now I want the same thing to be working on GAE! This is my app.yaml

```
application: <NAME>
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /assets
  static_dir: assets

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /support/.*
  script: index.php

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
  secure: always
```

Just to make sure that I get all the files routed correctly after someone provides me a solution. Here's the directory structure for the support desk (It's called hesk)-

[image]

I need a solution with wildcards so that `/support` works flawlessly with the sub-folders & everything.. also need to define static files. as you can see they are scattered all over the place.. not at all convenient but that's how it is! am poor at regex. So please have mercy on me.

**Update:**
I added updated the app.yaml a bit.. now all the php scripts from the support root & 1st level sub-directories work

```
- url: /support/(.*)/(.*)\.php$
  script: support/\1/\2.php

- url: /support/(.*)\.php$
  script: support/\1.php
```

But problem is there are a tons of sub-folders in this thing. see this snap below of the support/inc folder. how to handle that? do I have to manually put a url-script pair for all the possible number of sub-dir levels? This is so frustrating!

[image]

Comment: Again, you have the nesting wrong. The URLs are relative to the `app.yaml` file, so don't include `support/` in your script path.  The regex wildcard method handles all the nesting for you.  Just use: `- url: /(.+)\.php
  script: \1.php` as in the answer.

Comment: WAIT!  So you edited the question and moved your `app.yaml` somewhere?  Where is it now?

Comment: There is no separate app.yaml for the application that's running from `/support/`.. the one you saw is a long story. app.yaml is where it should be! at `/`

Comment: Dude there must be some misunderstanding.. I have my codeigniter app at `/` & the custom php based support desk called 'Hesk' is running at `/support/`

Comment: `/(.+)\.php script: \1.php` would only handle the php scripts directly called that are residing at `/` also it won't map `/` to `/index.php`

Comment: Not true.  Try it.  And you don't have to escape the period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution :**
Thanks GAEfan.. I kinda mixed n matched from your ideas & finally these are the needed handlers. It's running perfectly now!

```
#for all the static files residing at support root or at any other level
- url: /support/(.*\.(htm$|css$|js$|ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))$
  static_files: support/\1
  upload: support/.*\.(htm$|css$|js$|ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$)$
  application_readable: true

#for all the php files running at support root or at any other level
- url: /support/(.+)\.php
  script: support/\1.php

#for using index.php at support root or at any other level
- url: /support/(.*)
  script: support/\1/index.php
```

P.S : the handler below can run index.php from any other level but not support root

```
- url: /support/(.+)
  script: support/\1/index.php
```

Answer (score 2):

You are sending every call to `- url: /support/.*` to `index.php`.  What you want is a regex to send to the proper script:

```
- url: /support/(.+).php
  script: support/\1.php
```

**NOTE:** your `app.yaml` and `index.php` are located inside the `support` directory.  You will want `app.yaml` at the root, or you won't be able to access files outside the support dir. Is `support` the root of this application?

Remember: urls are relative to the `app.yaml` file

For files at the root level, you would use:

```
- url: /(.+).php
  script: \1.php
```

You will want to put your static files in a static directory, and use:

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

and access the files using, e.g.: `/static/hesk_javascript.js`

**UPDATE 2**
To handle static files using regex:

```
- url: /support/(.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg))$
  static_files: support/\1
  upload: support/.*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|woff|ttf|otf|eot|svg)$
  application_readable: true
```

Comment: you helped me realize that I forgot to add the support dir on the script value. but it's not working actually `- url: /support/
  script: support/index.php` helped me to get the root of support working, but whenever I use support/index.php or some other php file, am getting 404. also I need to have all the static files working too. Do you know how to get them?

Comment: See update.  You have a problem with the way your files are nested in the directories.

Comment: my problem is not how to define static dir.. I know how to.. anyways see my update now

Comment: You said, "also need to define static files. as you can see they are scattered all over the place", so I fixed that for you

Comment: man it's a 3rd party application.. do you think I would want to gather all the static files all over the dir & sub-dirs n put them in a single folder!? I think you have missed `- url: /assets
  static_dir: assets`! I already know that man!

Comment: Your static files solution was bang on.. I have the full solution now.. thanks man!